# Chat app in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to develop a chat app for BlackBerry. I did search, but found no documentation about developing a chat app for BlackBerry. The only things I found were BlackBerry Messenger and an XMPP library. There is no explanation of how to use the XMPP library in BlackBerry.

My question is whether building a chat app is possible on BlackBerry other than using BlackBerry Messenger. How do I use XMPP on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU have to figure out the way you want to do it. You can't just find a complete guide on how to make a chat application. Read how the xmpp protocol works. That not a BB only feature, so you should be able to find something about it..